# Doubt in getting yesterday's date using java

Tags: java

I want to get yesterday's date using java. I have used the following code but it is giving different date each time, Please check whether the code has to be change anywhere. Thanks in advance.

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter= 
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd ");
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    String previous = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+ "00:00:00.000000000";
    System.out.println("previous ="+previous);
    currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    String previousDate = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime())+ "00:00:00.000000000";
    Timestamp updateTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(previousDate);
    System.out.println("Update date ="+updateTimestamp);
```

This is the output i got when i ran lastly
**previous =2010-15-11 00:00:00.000000000 

Update date =2011-03-10 00:00:00.0**

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that you're using 'yyyy-mm-dd' which pulls the year-minute-day.  Instead use 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Comment: And for an overview of all valid patterns, just check `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 10):

You used mm in your pattern, so you're using minutes instead of months.

If you wanna use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), a simpler date framework, you could do the following :

```
DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000000000");
DateTime now = new DateTime();
System.out.println("Previous :" + format.print(now);
DateTime oneDayAgo = now.minusDays(1);
System.out.println("Updated :" + format.print(oneDayAgo);
```

Comment: So `DateTime oneDayAgo = now.minusDays(1);` is so much less crappy than `currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);` that you advocate adding a 3rd party library just for this?

Comment: No. But Joda Time, in general, takes care of all the little pitfalls the Java implementation on Date is full. It's just a good practice of using it if your're playing with dates.

I'm not a JodaTime integrist, just wanted to give an alternate solution.

Comment: I should add I voted for the current best solution, indicating what was false in his example. Joda Time helped me so much on trivial date problems with Java, so I just wanted to share it :)

Comment: @Valentin: The 'pitfall' raja fell into was the difference between the formatting patterns mm and MM. How is JoDa taking care of this problem?

Comment: As I said, I understood, my solution (changing libs) was a bit overkill, and I didn't read really well the question. Could we move on to another subject, or am I going to suffer an eternity of torment for suggesting Joda Time ?

Comment: using joda time would not have solved the problem because the user used mm in stead of MM

Comment: ok, added the good answer, now could everyone stop telling me the same thing again and again ?

Answer (score 6):

Your date format pattern string is wrong. "mm" is minutes, "MM" is months. You could have solved this easily by looking at the intermediate results looking like "2010-52-11...".

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.roll(Calendar.DATE, false); //you can also use add(int, int)
System.out.println(cal.toString());
```

All in standard Java since 1.1.  Also have a look at GregorianCalendar if you need to.  Read the docs to see how it handles daylight savings etc.

Comment: Grabbing `GregorianCalendar` separately is unnecessary. The `Calendar#getInstance()` already returns it.

Comment: True, given that GregorianCalendar is the 'only' implementation of Calendar in standard Java.  The docs might be useful to read through, however.

Comment: Cogsy: GregorianCalendar is the only Calendar implementation with a public API. Sun's Java 6 include implementations for the Japanese and Buddhist (Thai) calendars as well.