# How can I get yesterday's date without using Calendar in Java and without a timestamp just the date?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I have wrote a method to get the current date in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` and want to be able to also create another method for getting yesterday's date, the day before the current date.  All this needs is the date and not the timestamp.  I am not trying to use `Calendar` as well. I have set up the current date this way:

```
public class DateWithNoTimestamp
{
       private static final String CURRENT_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

       public final static String getCurrentDate()
       {
               DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(CURRENT_DATE_FORMAT);
               Date date = new Date();
               return dateFormat.format(date);
       } 
}
```

This works to get the current date, now the separate method `getYesertdayDate()` I'm having trouble with.  How can I set it up in a similar way as I did with `getCurrentDate()` while subtracting one day ?

Comment: "How do I cross a river in a row boat without using oars?" Idunno, I guess you can paddle with your hands?.. In Java that would mean writing a subset of `Calendar`.

Comment: Duplicate of many Questions. Search on terms such as: (a) Java date-only, and (b) Java yesterday or Java subtract days. Specifically, see [this Answer by Przemek](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33893147/642706) for the modern solution.

Answer (score 27):

You could simply subtract `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` milliseconds from the date and format that value:

```
Date yesterday = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L));
```

That's the quick-and-dirty way, and, as noted in the comments, it might break when daylight savings transitions happen (two days per year). Recommended alternatives are the [Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425236/get-yesterdays-date-using-date), the [Joda API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244444/doubt-in-getting-yesterdays-date-using-java) or the new JDK 8 time API:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it...

Comment: Good point! Didn't come to my mind :)

Comment: "That's the quick-and-dirty way" You forgot to add that it's going to break on at least two days of the year - specifically, on days when the daylight saving time is activated or deactivated.

Answer (score 16):

I found `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils` is more intuitive and easy to use.

For your question

```
Date date = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
return sdf.format(date);
```

will do the trick. And it works well also in JDK7 or below.

Answer (score 16):

With Java 8 and later, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class:

```
LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1L);
```

Comment: I suggest always passing the optional `ZoneId` to `now` rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can change at any moment even *during* runtime. `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Date() object for "yesterday":

```
private static final String CURRENT_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

public final static String format(Date date) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(CURRENT_DATE_FORMAT);
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public final static String formatToday() {
    return format(new Date());
}

public final static String formatYesterday() {
    return format(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24*3600*1000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class DateWithNoTimestamp
{
       private static final String CURRENT_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

       public final static String getCurrentDate()
       {
           DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(CURRENT_DATE_FORMAT);
           Date date = new Date();
           date .setTime(date.getTime()-24*60*60*1000);  // Subtract 24*60*60*1000 milliseconds
           return dateFormat.format(date);
       } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is on par with what I am trying to do.  A machine takes a Date down to a millisecond so this makes a lot of sense.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This    to get the Date of Yesterday:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    long yourDateMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()- (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                 Time yourDate = new Time();
         yourDate.set(yourDateMillis);

    String formattedDate = yourDate.format("%d-%m-%Y");
    txtViewYesterday.setText(formattedDate);}
```